# What does ''arbitrary shape'' mean?

Tags: svg

I have started some work on SVG graphics and i constantly come across the word ''arbitrary shapes''.

What exactly is an arbitrary shape?

Comment: arbitrary shape = any shape? maybe a specific link would help us clear up any confusion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `arbitrary shape` is just that.. An arbitrary shape.

The word arbitrary in this context means `any` as in: **not a specified, or specific, kind of shape**.

This is not really a programming question though.. But rather an English language question.

Comment: for example if i use a path tool and draw a random shape? So non arbitrary would be a rectangle, triangle, circle?

Comment: Even a rectangle can be an example of an arbitrary shape. Compare that with the opposite of arbitrary such as in the expression: _the shape must be a parallelogram_  in that case the shape is not arbitrary, but rather constrained to be of a specific kind.

Comment: i think i somehow got it then. thanks!

Comment: It might be best to look up the usage of the word `arbitrary` in a thesaurus, when used as an adjective to describe a noun (I.e not just shapes) ;)